# How do I get a local variable from one function and use it for a different function in my code?

Tags: c#, variables

I am making a slot machine, and I want the var 'bet' in `betValidation()` to be used in the `result()` function. My goal is if two of the random number generated in `firstRandomNumberGenerator()` are the same, the bet that the player bets will be tripled and will be added back to his current amount of chips. ): But in order to do that, I'll need to get bet (a local variable) and place it in `result()` but I don't know how.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace randomProjectTAKE3
{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main()
        {
            float playerChips = 1000;

            Console.Write("Player's Chips: ");
            Console.WriteLine(playerChips);

            Console.Write("1. Play Slot  ");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Exit");

            choice();
            result();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static void Update()
        {
        }

        static void choice()
        {
            float choice = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                firstRandomNumberGenerator();
            }

            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        static void betValidation()
        {
            float playerChips = 1000;
            float currentPlayerChips;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your bet: ");
            **var bet = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());**

            if ((bet <= 0) || (bet > playerChips))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid bet.\n");
                Main();
            }
        }

        static void firstRandomNumberGenerator()
        {

            betValidation();


            Random r = new Random();
            int firstNumber = r.Next(2, 8);
            int secondNumber = r.Next(2, 8);
            int thirdNumber = r.Next(2, 8);

            Console.Write(firstNumber);
            Console.Write(secondNumber);
            Console.Write(thirdNumber);
            Console.Write("\n");

        }

        **static void result()**
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to make this happen, one way is to move the bet into the scope of the program as a field (the name _currentBet would be useful), rather than declared in the function so it can be referenced as many times as needed.

Then when the player places the bet, you can parse and assign to the variable.  This would also be ideal with your player's chips.

```
class Program
{
private float _playersChips = 1000;
private float _currentBet;

static void Main()
{
//So on and so forth.
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have a question. I did what you told me to (put playerchips and currentbet at the top and add the underscores) but then, this shows:                                                                           
            Console.WriteLine(_playerChips);     <-- it gets a red squiggy line saying:  the name "_playerChips" does not exist in the current context

Comment: you need to make them static

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I have is to pass the variable `By Reference` from a method to another,
check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, ok... so are you familiar with [Global Variables](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable)?

Looking at your code, you're writing a console application in a [procedural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) (rather than [object-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) style... Whilst this can be done in C#, for larger applications, it can make code maintenance a big headache.

Regardless, I'll try and help you out...

Miles's answer is essentially using a Global Variable instead of a local one, which is a good suggestion when programming in a procedural style, however, another option for you is to make playerChips a [reference method parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/14akc2c7.aspx) (as suggested by Hussein) which can be passed (and modified) between methods... so (using both of their suggestions) your code would change to work as follows:

```
class Program
{
    public static float _playerChips = 1000;

    private static void Main()
    {            
        Console.Write("Player's Chips: ");

        Console.WriteLine(_playerChips);
        Console.Write("1. Play Slot  ");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Exit");

        choice(ref _playerChips);
        result(_playerChips);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void choice(ref float playerChips)
    {
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            firstRandomNumberGenerator(ref playerChips);
        }

        if (choice == 2)
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private static void betValidation(ref float playerChips, ref float bet)
    {                        

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your bet: ");
        bet = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if ((bet <= 0) || (bet > playerChips))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid bet.\n");
            Main();
        }
    }

    private static void firstRandomNumberGenerator(ref float playerChips)
    {
        float bet = 0;
        betValidation(ref playerChips, ref bet);

        System.Random r = new System.Random();

        int firstNumber = r.Next(2, 8);
        int secondNumber = r.Next(2, 8);
        int thirdNumber = r.Next(2, 8);

        if (firstNumber == secondNumber || firstNumber == thirdNumber || thirdNumber == secondNumber)
            playerChips = playerChips + (bet * 3);

        Console.Write(firstNumber);
        Console.Write(secondNumber);
        Console.Write(thirdNumber);
        Console.Write("\n");
    }

    private static void Update()
    {
        return;
    }

    private static void result(float playerChips)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, I've also changed the *choice()* method you wrote to call Environment.Exit() and exit the program - the reason for this is, by executing Main() you're essentially calling methods within methods within methods and increasing your [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) which will eventually lead to a [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)... I would consider changing your Main() method to use a loop based on choice() returning a result rather than just calling Main() from the betValidation method again (however I have not done this for you).